# Можно ли создать декоратор из класса?

Tags: python, ооп, декоратор

Можно ли создать декоратор из класса?

Comment: Добавьте метку python-3.

Comment: Именно "декоратор ИЗ класса"? Или просто "декоратор класса"? Это две разные вещи. Можно создать и то, и другое, но "декоратор ИЗ класса" - это что-то необычное, я с ходу даже не могу придумать, для чего бы это могло понадобиться.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно:

```
class decor(object):
    def __init__(self, subj ):
        self.subbj = subj

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print( f" args: {args}, kwargs:{kwargs}" )
        ret = self.subbj( *args, **kwargs )
        print( f" return: {ret}" )
        return ret

@decor
def foo(arg):
    return arg+1

r = foo(12)
```

Comment: Инициализации класса не вижу.